# what is the difference between supply and allocate?

Tags: differences

what is the difference between supplying X with Y and allocating X to Y?

Can anyone give explain with examples?

Comment: You _supply_ goods or equipment to people (make them available). You _allocate_ the goods to the particular people who need them, or for a particular purpose.

Comment: To allocate is merely to assign; to supply is to actually deliver. Which dictionaries are you using, that didn't explain that?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I used https://dictionary.cambridge.org/. I do research on plant science, where people interchangeably use allocate and supply. Not everyone is a native English speaker!

Comment: Thanks, Kathiravan. 

When you do research where people use "allocate" and "supply" interchangeably, how does that make them correct?

Why would you be Asking, unless you doubted them?

Did you notice, much of the point is "not everyone is a native English speaker"?

Answer (score -2):

Extending Kate Bunting's comment above:

*Electrical power is **supplied** by underground cables.* (is made available to everybody)

*The government is **allocating** £10 million for health education.* (a particular sum by a particular institution for a particular purpose)

Comment: supply = provide with; give, etc.; allocate = reserve for a purpose, like allocation in the budget, etc.

Comment: Wholly true, Shogun, and how does that explain the difference?

Answer (score -2):

To me the biggest difference is: supply is to give, and be made available, while allocate is to distribute.

The volunteers **supplied** food for the shelter.

The agency will **allocate** a million dollars too victims of the hurricane.

Comment: "Allocate" definitely does not mean "distribute".